# Are there any .NET based implementations of a Central Authentication Service?

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc

Before I reinvent the wheel, are they any .NET implementations of a Central Authentication Service? I have a need to authenticate users on a single site for various other sites, all under my control. This isn't very complicated, but I just wanted to see what's out there. An MVC version would be preferred.

Comment: Do you mean for Jasig CAS? There is a SO tag for that, maybe it would help adding it to this Q?

Answer (score 3):

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/106439/Single-Sign-On-SSO-for-cross-domain-ASP-NET-applic

Well explained with sample code, FYI.

You may also refer: [SSO Library on asp.net C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5977616/sso-library-on-asp-net-c-sharp)